# Accessing static member function gives: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c++11, static, static-methods

I am sure this is a noob C++ question and just reflects my poor understanding.

I have a file

**A.cxx** contains,

```
#include "Rishab.h"
#include <future>

void functionToRun() {
  while (true) {
    Rishab::hello();
  }
}

int main() {
    std::future<void> futureVariable = std::async(std::launch::async, functionToRun);
}
```

**Rishab.h**

```
#ifndef __METRIC_RISHAB_H__
#define __METRIC_RISHAB_H__

class Rishab {
public:
    static void hello();

};
#endif
```

**Rishab.cxx**

```
#include "Rishab.h"

void Rishab::hello() {
}
```

When I try to compile this the linker throws error,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Rishab::hello()", referenced from:
      functionToRun() in A.cxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

PS: These files are a part of a bigger project, so there is a Makefile.

I have gone over other answers online but most of them cater to `static variable` not being defined (and only declared). But my question involves `static function`

Comment: And the ***actual*** command that executes the linker is...?

Comment: The error message is telling you that the linker, while trying to combine all the separately-compiled object files for each _translation unit_ (_i.e._ each file containing source code), it could not resolve the existence of the function `void Rishab::hello()`.  This most likely means that you did not actually provide the object code from the compiled `Rishab.cxx` file as part of your invocation to the linker.  As such, it doesn't know where this function is implemented.

Comment: Found it. Sorry for the stupid question. There was a CMakeLists.txt where the file Rishab.cxx had to be added. Now it works. I can accept the answer if @paddy you post your answer. The above comment solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the linker, while trying to combine all the separately-compiled object code for each *translation unit* (i.e. each file containing source code), it could not resolve the existence of the function `void Rishab::hello()`.

This most likely means that you did not actually provide the object code from the compiled `Rishab.cxx` file as part of your invocation to the linker. As such, the linker doesn't know where to find the implementation of that function and so it cannot assemble a full program.

Note that the header (often called the *interface*) is what declares symbols that can be shared across your source files (often called the *implementation*):

- At compile time, each individual source file only needs to know about interfaces.  It is free to use these interfaces without needing to worry about how they're implemented.  This is what allows a program to be split into many different parts, without having to compile everything in one hit.  In simple terms, your interfaces create placeholders for actual compiled code.
- At link time, all of the compiled parts must then be connected together, and all interfaces must be resolved to their implementations.  If the linker can't find the implementation, then it is an error.

Any time you see a symbol resolution error like this, the most likely causes are:

- you forgot to define something that was declared in a header
- you made a typo in either the declaration or the definition
- you are using namespaces incorrectly
- you forgot to tell the linker everything it needs to know (*e.g.* give it all the relevant object files)
- you are using a stale/outdated version of one of your object files (perhaps you didn't notice compilation failed, and you tried to link anyway)